# If someone answers his own question why don't they get upvotes?

Tags: discussion, up-votes, self-answer

I have posted many questions, of which I found the solution myself after doing lot of debugging. But the sad thing is that neither my questions nor my answers gets any upvotes. Why? Shouldn't you upvote someone who was able to find the solution on his own?

Comment: This would depend on the question and the answer. If people don't think the Q/A is useful or helpful to future people, they may not feel inclined to upvote. Maybe link to the question/answer?

Comment: Bad grammar has a deterrent effect for the upvotes.

Comment: Not everyone has English as his/her native language.

Comment: @Doda Also not mine, but I do what I can. [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163) is a quick checklist.

Comment: I checked your selfanswered questions. I think the lack of ups has two reasons: 1) bad grammar (it is enough if you follow the checklist I've linked) 2) you have a low reputation (it will self-solve with time). Another thing: if I self-answer a question where also other answers are coming, I prefer to accept a different one as mine.

Comment: @peterh Thanks a lot sir. I will try my best to implement the same. Btw am i making any grammatical mistakes here ?

Comment: @peterh I edited some of my question just as you suggested here have a look first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46773416/rendering-different-templates-to-the-same-url-pattern-in-django second: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46716998/jquery-effects-not-working-on-bootstrap-modal-close-class

Comment: What makes you think they don't? I have a single self-answered question on [su]. It has 28 upvotes and the answer has 23 upvotes. The trick is to ask a good question and provide a good answer ...

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't know about the question but answers were good.

Comment: @Doda They may be good but they also have to be useful to other people ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

People vote answers up because they're helpful, not because its author is smart. Good answers gets many upvotes because the comunity think it's helpful to further readers (or themselves). There are many zero score accepted answers, mostly because the community don't think it'd be useful to further readers, as well as the quality of the answer isn't bad enough to be voted down. So you should post answers "not too specific" to a certain scenario, so they'd get upvoted.

The above text doesn't fully apply on Meta, though.